# what is the difference between "new Observable()" and "of()" in RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

What is the difference between `new Observable()` and `of()` in `RxJs`?

In my test cases when I try to return `new Observable()` it gives me a wired error and if I replace it with the `of()` from Rxjs it works fine.

My impression was `Observable.create()`, `new Observable()` and `of()` does same thing.

```
someService.getMethod().pipe(
  ...
  catchError((e) => {
    // some operation
    // return new Observable(false as any);  // ----> creates error
    return of(false as any); // this works perfectly
  })
)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`Observable.create()`** and **`new Observable()`** essentially do the same thing.

> [**From Anatomy of an Observable**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#anatomy-of-an-observable):
>
> `Rx.Observable.create` is an alias for the `Observable` `constructor`, and it takes one argument: the `subscribe` function.

**`Observable.of`**, on the other hand is a `static` method on `Observable`. It creates an `Observable` for you, that emits value(s) that you specify as argument(s) immediately one after the other, and then emits a complete notification.

**Issue with your implementation:**

Your implementation of a Custom Observable is wrong. When you `new` up an Observable, you have to pass in a `subscribe` function to its [**`constructor`**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-constructor-constructor) which has an `observer` as an arg. This `observer` has methods like `next`, `error`, and `complete` on it which gets called at those particular instances in the lifecycle of that observable.

You should also expose a `Subscription` Object that has an `unsubscribe` method on it, which can then be used by the consumer for doing any clean-up.

**Here's how it can be implemented in general:**

```
const yourCustomObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
  observer.next("This pushes new value to the consumer");
  observer.error("This pushes an error to the consumer");
  observer.complete();

  return function unsubscribe() {
    // When the consumer unsubscribes, clean up data ready for next subscription.
  };
});
```

## For your specific use-case you can either use:

**`new Observable(...)`**:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
...
someService.getMethod().pipe(
  ...
  catchError((e) => {
    // some operation
    return new Observable(observer => observer.next(false));
  })
)
```

**`Observable.create`**:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
...
someService.getMethod().pipe(
  ...
  catchError((e) => {
    // some operation
    return Observable.create(observer => observer.next(false));
  })
)
```

**`of`**:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
...
someService.getMethod().pipe(
  ...
  catchError((e) => {
    // some operation
    return of(false);
  })
)
```

**`from`**:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
...
someService.getMethod().pipe(
  ...
  catchError((e) => {
    // some operation
    return from([false]);
  })
)
```

Have a look at this [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observable-creation?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for ref.

**When to use what?**

`new Observable(...)` or `Observable.create(...)` gives you a more fine grain control where you can define your own `subscribe` function and do whatever you want in it. So you might want to use it for implementing custom Observables that can't be generally created using the `static` methods provided on `Observable`. For simple use cases like yours, however, using `Observable.of` or `Observable.from` for that matter, would suffice.

Comment: Thanks for explaining well. so when should `Observable.of()` need to use and where `new Observable()` can be used? And is `Observable.create()` is same as `new Observable()`

Comment: From what I've read, `new Observable()` gives you a more fine grain control where you can define your own `subscribe` function that essentially lets your consumer do several different things. For simple use cases like yours however, using `Observable.of` or `Observable.from` would suffice.

Comment: Or just use subjects, they are the bread and butter of the RxJs developers toolkit. Hardly anybody rolls their own observables once they discover subjects and behavior subjects.